# How do I redirect to another page with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, button

I know it's a simple question but I really can't find anything on Google. Sorry if I'm not searching right.
I created 2 pages and in the first one I have a button.
What should I write in the C# code to change to redirect me on the second page?
I usually know my way around C# but I'm totally new in ASP.

Comment: How do you write ASP in C#?  I've seen C# used for ASP.Net but that isn't the same as ASP to my mind.  There should be a form tag if you want to change where the submitted form goes I believe.

Comment: @JB King: I think he means asp.net, it's just a pain in the ass to keep adding ".net" every time.

Comment: That's what I thought, but sometimes it is better to ask and get that clarified than assume and step on someone's toes.

Comment: Sorry. I meant Asp.Net but as R0MANARMY said it's a pain to keep adding ".net" every time and that's why I forgot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aspx page to redirect to a new page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093081/aspx-page-to-redirect-to-a-new-page)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the button [onclick event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx).

In the event handler put:

```
Response.Redirect("YOUR_NEW_PAGE");
```

[Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309(VS.90).aspx) or [Server.Transfer](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm)

[Slightly more complicated, and probably not what you need a cross page post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)

Comment: Yes. Actually he answered what whould have probably been my next question with that CPP article. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure from your question whether you're after ASP VB or C#...so...

// C#

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Server.Transfer("Webform2.aspx");
}
```

' Visual Basic

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Server.Transfer("Webform2.aspx")
End Sub
```

For more information, I direct you to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/540y83hx%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I did write C# and the tag is also C#. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

Use one of these methods:

One-time redirect (HTTP 301)

```
Response.Redirect("page to redirect to");
```

Permanent redirect (HTTP 302), only available in ASP.NET 4.0

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("page to redirect to");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in the aspx itself (without writing any code) by using the PostBackUrl property of the button.

Comment: I know that this is old but thanks @adrianos, not that my error stopped my program but it was just annoying having the error in log4net.