# how can i redirect to another page in function that called by btnclick. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I wanna redirect to another page when i call a function
 here my button

```
<button id="test" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click()"> Button here </button>
```

here my button action

```
protected void Button1_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int ID = 0;
   Label5.Visible = false;

   ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);


  // somthing like 
  // Server.Transfer("~/Producter/Delete?id="+ id)
  // OR
  Response.Redirect("~/Producter/Delete?id="+ ID);

 }
```

Comment: what problem u having with this code

Comment: Nothing happes when i click on the button

Comment: see my answer, and then response me

Comment: you are firing the serverside event from client side, so check my answer for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect from one ASP.NET page to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947663/how-to-redirect-from-one-asp-net-page-to-another)

Answer (score 2):

since you are using regular html button, when clicked, it will execute `Button1_Click()` on the client side, instead of in code behind.

Change the button to :

```
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button here" />
```

Comment: when i put the mouse over the button, i see in the status bar url to the root.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the binding of the function Button1_Click() to the button. Try checking the Button1's OnClick property to make sure it links to the function Button1_Click().

Comment: Are you sure your button postbacks and triggers the Button1_Click event? Put a breakpoint in the function and see.

Comment: i put breakpoints but the program didnt stop there. 
 when i put the mouse over the butten, i se in the status bar Url to the root, then when i click  the page refreshing

Comment: weird. try recompiling the project.

Answer (score 0):

your Button1_Click function is correct, and I think the way you are calling from  object is wrong.

you should either use

```
 <asp:Button ID="btn_test" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

 protected void Button1_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 int ID = 0;
 Label5.Visible = false;

 ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);
 Response.Redirect("~/Producter/Delete?id="+ ID);

 }
```

or you should use html button object and call a webmethod like below

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#test').click(function(){
         $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Profile.aspx/update_phone",
                    data: "{'ProfessionalID':''}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function () { }
                });
     });
 });
 </script>
 <button id="test" runat="server"> Button here </button>

 [webmethod]
 public static void Button1_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  ....
  Response.Redirect("~/Producter/Delete?id="+ ID);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Response.Redirect("~/Producter/Delete?id="+ ID,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#test').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         //using jquery, you must import jquery library for it
        $('#buttonHidden').click();
     }
</script>
// your button here to call javascript
<button id="test" runat="server"> Button here </button>
// the hidden button just to hold the Button1_Click which is fired from fireClick()
<asp:Button ID="buttonHidden" runat="server" Style="display: none" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

also fix your code behind like this;

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int ID = 0;
   Label5.Visible = false;

   ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);


  // somthing like 
  // Server.Transfer("~/Producter/Delete?id="+ id)
  // OR
  Response.Redirect("~/Producter/Delete?id="+ ID);

 }
```