# asp.net change parameter in current URL for href

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Let's say I'm currently on `www.tacos.com/happy/burritos`, which is defined under my controller as `[RoutePrefix("{mood}/{food}'`.

I'm trying to use an asp.net function(maybe something like `@Url.route()`) to change it to `www.tacos.com/sad/burritos` by setting `mood = "sad"`.

Comment: Your question is too broad... fundamentally, the way web works is that browser sends a request and server replies with a response. Now if you want to change the URL (which is one and the same thing as a request) you would need to send a new request to the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aspx page to redirect to a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093081/aspx-page-to-redirect-to-a-new-page)

Comment: Take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you have a higher chance of getting help and finding the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick.

```
Response.Redirect("www.tacos.com/sad/burritos");
```

Based on [aspx-page-to-redirect-to-a-new-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093081/aspx-page-to-redirect-to-a-new-page)